# How to set up ARCore Pose in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore

Recently, my team tried to make a ARCore motion tracking app with Unity. The app reads a QR code and sets my current position and rotation data from QR code. Additionally, the app sets a pose from QR code data.

However, I have only found an API that gets pose in the reference document, not set pose. How can I set ARCore pose in Unity?

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on the last two sentences. Having difficulty understanding what you mean by 'GetPose'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Pose](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/arcore/reference/com/google/ar/core/Pose#extractTranslation())** of ArCamera (camera of ARCore device for the Unity's ArFrame) is just gettable, not settable.

There's no deep sense to make it settable because a 3D scene's origin will be placed at ArCamera's starting position when ArSession starts running. Thus 3D scene is living until ArSession will be destroyed (and axis origin is at the same place while a session is running).

Here's a code showing how to get ArCamera's Pose:

```
public class Frame {

    public static Pose Pose {

        get {
            var session = LifecycleManager.Instance.NativeSession;

            if (session == null) {
                return Pose.identity;
            }
            var camera = session.FrameApi.AcquireCamera();
            Pose result = session.CameraApi.GetPose(camera);
            session.CameraApi.Release(camera);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```